# Getting HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Tags: nginx

So I installed nginx in digitalocean droplet.. so far so good. But now I can't get a bootstrap template to show, I tried accessing a png file and nothing.

When entering

```
curl -I http ://104.131.23.214/sites/bootstrap/img/profile.png
```

*I get..*

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found <br>
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) <br>
Date: Sun, 03 Jul 2016 10:28:09 GMT <br>
Content-Type: text/html <br>
Content-Length: 177 <br>
Connection: keep-alive <br>
```

When entering `curl -I http://104.131.23.214`

*I get..*

```
root@ubuntu-nginx-1:~# curl -I http://104.131.23.214 <br>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK <br>
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) <br>
Date: Sun, 03 Jul 2016 10:32:04 GMT <br>
Content-Type: text/html <br>
Content-Length: 612 <br>
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 11:46:45 GMT <br>
Connection: keep-alive <br>
ETag: "5315bd25-264" <br>
Accept-Ranges: bytes <br>

..
```

For whatever reason **nginx** is giving me a **404** when accessing any directory..

My conf file looks like this..

```
events {}


http {

    include mime.types;

    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name 104.131.23.214;
        root /sites/bootstrap;

    }   

  }

..
```

I'm a complete noob so any help would be gladly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Nginx has excellent wiki at http://wiki.nginx.org for any complete noob. For your particular question, you may want to look into the logs (probably in /var/log/nginx/*.log) to understand what's going on. You might also want to include a `location` block (and possibly a `try_files` directive inside it too). If you have any trouble formatting questions here, please spend some time at http://serverfault.com/help/formatting .

Comment: I entered /var/log/nginx/*.log and get -bash: /var/log/nginx/access.log: Permission denied ?

Comment: Your site's home page and the images are okay as of now. How did you solve it?

Comment: I made a super noob mistake.. I was editing the wrong nginx.conf file which was inside my /root/nginx-1.9.15.. instead of editing the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf... lol, now everything is working fine. I'm still getting "Permission denied" when I run /var/log/nginx/access.log, will that be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comment, in your `server` block, you may want to add the following (below the `root` line):

```
location /img/ {
}
```

Then reload your config with `nginx -s reload` and try your curl command again.

Comment: I managed to get the site working. But I still get 404 Not Found when accessing files.. ? (http://104.131.23.214 works fine) (http://104.131.23.214/sites/bootstrap/img/profile.png gives me 404 Not Found)

Comment: If you've kept your `root` line as is, it means that you should not need the `/sites/bootstrap/` bit to retrieve your image. So what if you do:
`curl -i http ://104.131.23.214/img/profile.png` ?

Comment: Fantastic! I can access all files in browser when I remove the /sites/bootstrap/. But, when I run curl -i http://104.131.23.214/img/profile.png in terminal I get a mess of code that looks like this.... "%L@.����x3�4>�_R��Q�k���/�`{i��" Any ideas why?

Comment: EDIT: curl i was the issue, I needed to use curl I (capital i).. all good! Thank you David!